# std::move on c-style pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, move

Are there any circumstances under which you should use `std::move` on a c-style pointer `T*` (not `unique_ptr<T>`, `shared_ptr<T>` etc) instead of simply copying pointer?

Comment: For fundamental types like pointers, moving is equivalent to copying. You could use `std::move` with a pointer, it'll be a no-op. This may be useful e.g. in generic code that works with both raw and smart pointers.

Comment: `int i = 5; int j = std::move(i);` does not do anything special, it's just a copy.  Likewise, `int* i  = new i{5}; int* j = std::move(i);` does not do anything special, it's just a copy.  A *move* isn't magic.  If there's nothing to actually *move*, it's just a **copy**.